# issue with uploading file to ftp server

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to the FTP server. Here is my code -

```
        $csv_filename =  "orders/"."alp"."-".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";

        $filename = "alp"."-".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";

        $fd = fopen ($csv_filename, "w");

        file_put_contents($csv_filename, $data);

        $ch = curl_init();
        $localfile = $csv_filename;
        $fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp.mydomain.com/orders/'.$filename);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'uname:pwd');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 21); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
        curl_exec ($ch);
        $error_no = curl_error($ch);
```

This code works perfectly before 1 month and I know there are no any other settings made on the server. But suddenly it is throwing error -

```
Failed to connect to ftp.mydomain.com port 21: Connection timed out
```

FTP ports are open for the servers. Also, if I check to login with Filezilla with the same credentials, on my local machine, it throws the `connection time out` error. Also checked to login to Filezilla, with another two machines,  they worked there. Can anybody suggest me some solutions to overcome this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can guess is that your IP address is blocked or something. Maybe to many connections?